# Strategy when working with imperfect Z values in a standard normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

So if you must find the `X` value greater than 10% in `Z = (X - u) / σ`. If you look up in the Z value table, there is the option 1.28 (0.1003) or 12.9 (0.0985), what if I want exactly `0.100`, how would I calculate the Z value for this ..

Similarly if you're trying to find percentage for a Z value with 3 decimal places (table only shows 2), how would you go about this, the answer for this is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3055420/find-the-value-of-normal-distribution-with-a-3-decimal-places-z-score-using-tabl) , but quite frankly I don't understand it (specifically how he/she gets the weighted sums o.3 and 0.7), surely there is a more concise explanation.

*Thank you, let me know how I can improve on this question if neccessary.*

Comment: [Method of false position](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regula_falsi), and [linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation).

Answer (score 0):

If you want *exactly* $0.100$, the $Z$-value you want is very likely to be an irrational number, and hence not representable on a computer (or on a piece of paper, except indirectly, using a name like $\pi$ or $e$, or an unresolved computation, like $\arctan(1)$).

As for your "surely there is a more concise explanation," the explanation you point to is two sentences and about 200 characters!

Comment: Yes i understand it is very likely to be an irrational number, how do I calculate it though (considering I will round it off)?  I mean like a 'better' or clearer explanation

Comment: All my answers are wrong by a few 1/100th of decimal points compared to the answer sheet my professor gave me, but she doesn't explain how she finds these specific irrational Z values and etc. like I explain in my question. I hope you understand and can help me

Comment: I already *have* helped you: I've shown you that your uses of "exact" and "concise" are inappropriate and didn't communicate what you actually needed. You really can't expect us to be mind-readers and answer the question you *should* have asked. On the other hand, a 1-on-1 discussion with your professor might give you the insight you need on these particular problems, because *she* can ask you to clarify or re-state things in real time, and using the terminology that's part of the shared context of your particular course.

Comment: This isn't an answer at all (I wonder if you even read it properly), you haven't helped at all, why are you here if it's just to make petty observations and comments. One user commented two links with the calculation to my two questions in 3 words. The attitude on some people..

Comment: It's an answer to **exactly** what you asked for -- it's just one that you don't like. The first paragraph points out that you're asking for something it's impossible to provide, and the second shows that you already have the thing you've asked for.  But I can see how you'd be annoyed that someone would *volunteer* their time to do the very thing you asked. Seriously...the nerve of it!

Comment: I'm perfectly grateful for volunteers, but you can sniff a snobby StackExchange 'volunteer' from a mile away

Comment: Exactly what I asked for? "there is the option 1.28 (0.1003) or 12.9 (0.0985), what if I want exactly 0.100" , Please show me where you told me what z value to use? (this is quite literally the question), what you wrote should be put in a comment, it's not an answer the fact you put it in an answer alongside your attitude is enough proof to me you are being petty, I can't stand that